# Wrong number or type of arguments while inserting Blob null in Stored Procedure

Tags: java, database, oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc

i have following stored procedure in oracle database

```
    create or replace procedure cust_details(idValue    Custdetails.id_value%type,
                                                     idUser    Custdetails.id_user%type,
                                                     idType    Custdetails.id_type%type,
                                                     nickName  Custdetails.nickname%type,
                                                     imageData Custdetails.IMAGE%type) IS
  bene_id     number(10);
  current_seq number(10);
  isExist     number(2);
BEGIN

  select count(*)
    into isExist
    from iddetails
   where id_value = idValue;

  if isExist = 0 then
    select beneficiary_seq.nextval into current_seq from dual;
    insert into details
      (beneficiary_id, date_added)
    values
      (current_seq, sysdate);
    insert into Custdetails
      (beneficiary_id, id_user, nickname,image)
    valuesnumber 
      (current_seq, idUser, nickName,imageData);
    insert into iddetails
      (beneficiary_id, id_type, id_value)
    values
      (current_seq, idType, idValue);
  else
    select beneficiary_id
      into bene_id
      from iddetails
     where id_value = idValue;
    insert into Custdetails
      (beneficiary_id, id_user, nickname,image)
    values
      (bene_id, idUser, nickName,imageData);
  end if;
END;

--Custdetails.idValue is varchar2(40)
--Custdetails.IMAGE is Blob
```

and i call it from java class like following:

```
 CallableStatement callableStatement = con.prepareCall("{CALL cust_details(?,?,?,?,?)}");
    callableStatement.setString(1, "9855154");
callableStatement.setString(2, "123");
callableStatement.setString(3, "sdsd");
callableStatement.setString(4, "ssdsd");
    byte [] imageData = l_rs.getBlob  (0); // setting bytes
    if(// if byte array has data){ 
        Blob imgDataBlob = con.createBlob();
        imgDataBlob.setBytes(1, imageData);
        callableStatement.setBlob(5, imgDataBlob);
    }
    else{
        // even this is giving same error i also tried OracleTypes.Blob
        callableStatement.setNull  (2,  java.sql.Types.BLOB); 
    }
        callableStatement.execute();
```

but calling this procedure give following error  in both if and else cases

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
>           PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'CUST_DETAILS'

any idea what i am doing wrong here

Comment: Have you tried with Oracle specific datatypes (casting the statement to `OracleCallableStatement` and using `oracle.sql.BLOB`) ?

Comment: yes i tried (OracleTypes.BLOB) but same error

Comment: @user460293 Check whether execution is reaching in if and else part.

Comment: @user460293 - casting the `callableStatement` to `OracleCallableStatement` isn't the same thing as specifying `OracleTypes.BLOB`; did you try casting as well?

Comment: @user460293 I have modified my answer to cater null.

Comment: @user460293 In this line are you getting blob `byte [] imageData = l_rs.getBlob  (0);` If so are you getting it from resultSet?

Comment: yes i checked it on debug it is showing byte []

Comment: @user460293 How `l_rs.getBlob (0);` can be received in a byte variable? It should be `Blob imgDataBlob = l_rs.getBlob (0);` And why `l_rs.getBlob (0);` is `0`? What is the column index in your table which is having blob datatype?

Comment: actually l_rs.getBlob is object of MYResultSet Class in which i have override the method of getBlob() and it return byte[] believe me it is returning data, but in else case i am alos getting same error where it is java.sql.type.blob

Comment: @user460293 Which driver do you use and what is the database version?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19527/discussion-between-polppan-and-user460293)

Comment: @user460293 What are the details of your procedure? Could you post the code by editing your question?

Comment: i am using oracle11g with ojdbc14.jar

Comment: @user460293 Presume that you are passing all values to the procedure, because here there are only arguments being passed `CALL cust_details(?,?)`

Comment: @user460293 is this a typo error or ? `callableStatement.setBlob(2, "123");` And if possible come to chat discussion

Comment: @user460293 Remove this part from your procedure and try `INSERT INTO iddetails (beneficiary_id, id_type, id_value
          )
    VALUES   (current_seq, idtype, idvalue
       );`

Comment: but i need this part did find any problem in this part?

Comment: @user460293 For time being, just for debugging and I am guessing.

Comment: how can i chat to you i never chat before on stackoverflow?

Comment: Click this link `automatically move this discussion to chat?`

Comment: Please move extended discussions to [chat], this comment thread is getting quite long.

Comment: @user460293 Execute procedure from sqlplus by passing blob as null and see it is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the following which works fine, driver I am using `Ojdbc14.jar`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_proc (idvalue      NUMBER,
    imagedata     tobedeleted.img%TYPE
                                                )
IS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tobedeleted
      VALUES   (idvalue, imagedata
                  );
END my_proc;
```

Java code

```
    ResultSet res = sta.executeQuery(
            "SELECT * FROM TOBEDELETED for update "); 
          while (res.next()) {
             myblob = res.getBlob("IMG");

          }       
    callablestatement = 
            conn.prepareCall("{CALL my_proc(?,?)}");
    callablestatement.setInt(1, 100);        
            if(myblob==null){            
        callablestatement.setNull(2,java.sql.Types.BLOB); 

    }
    else {
        byte[] chuck = {(byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00,
                  (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00};
                myblob.setBytes(1,chuck);
    callablestatement.setBlob(2,myblob); 
    }
    int affectedRows = callablestatement.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Presumably `IMG` is not null, so `myblob` is not null either? Making the first six bytes of the `blob` null isn't the same as having a null `blob`. I think the OP is OK when there is something to pass to the parameter, it's when there isn't (in the `else` branch) that there's an issue with `setNull()`.

Comment: @AlexPoole I have modified my answer to cater null, it works perfectly. I guess it might be something to do with driver, only guessing.